# how to put the child content inside the parent without import on Vue JS

Tags: vuejs3

I want to not need to import a child component.
and Manipulation within the parent

On ReactJS is like that

```
`export const PrivateRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    component={props =>
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <div>
       
          <Component {...props} />

        </div>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }
  />
);`
```

On vue i want do something like that

The child :

```
<template>
  title
<test>//parent

  <div>Content</div>//child
</test>
 
</template>
```

on Parent Test like that

```
<template lang="">
    <div>
        Hello
       <component></component> //Content Child

      
    </div>
</template>
```

how do i do, can someone help me?